# Synchronization between SQL Server CE and SQL Server

Tags: .net, sql-server, ado.net, sql-server-ce, data-synchronization

How to synchronize data with SQL Server Standard Edition and SQL Server Compact Edition?
I hope you will give positive answer regarding this question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 3 different sync technologies with SQL Server Compact 3.5 and SQL Server:
Merge replication, ADO.NET Sync Framework and RDA

Comment: Can u give me example of ADO.NET Sync framework technologies?

Comment: LMGTFY: http://mobileworld.appamundi.com/blogs/andywigley/archive/2008/12/08/building-a-sync-services-for-ado-net-solution-for-mobile-devices.aspx